# match up two files in matlab

Tags: matlab, join, time

I have multiple files with varying file lengths.

file 1 is a .txt file of length 86400 X 10
file  2 is a  .csv file of length  144 X 10

Now this is the case when both the files have all data , but lot of times i have missing time stamps in middle so the length of the file1 is 1000-86400  X 10
and the file 2 is  10-144 X 10

Now I want to write a third file  of length  144 X 20 to include all the columns of file 2 and file 1( I am averaging the 86400 down to 144).

My problem is I am not able to match up the times properly to create the third file 
Any help?

#### file2

```
datetime, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6 ......       
9/15/2010 0:00, 8.8, 3.8, 2.8, 7.3, 0, 9.9      
9/15/2010 0:10, 10.1, 8.4, 5.1, 7.7, 0, 8.1       
9/15/2010 0:20, 8.8, 5.4, 7.6, 7.1, 0, 10.3     
9/15/2010 0:30, 5.7, 8.8, 7.1, 1.6, 0, 6.8      
9/15/2010 0:50, 7.9, 9.2, 6.4, 6.2, 0, 8.4        
9/15/2010 1:20, 0.6, 5.85, 8.1, 9.8, 0, 0.6
```

#### file 1

```
datetime, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6......        
9/15/2010 0:00:01, 8.8, 3.8, 2.8, 7.3, 0, 9.9     
9/15/2010 0:00:02, 10.1, 8.4, 5.1, 7.7, 0, 8.1      
9/15/2010 0:00:03, 8.8, 5.4, 7.6, 7.1, 0, 10.3      
9/15/2010 0:00:09, 5.7, 8.8, 7.1, 1.6, 0, 6.8      
9/15/2010 0:00:10, 7.9, 9.2, 6.4, 6.2, 0, 8.4        
9/15/2010 1:00:03, 0.6, 5.85, 8.1, 9.8, 0, 0.6
```

I use to read the files

```
fid = fopen('file1.csv', 'rt');    
a = textscan(fid, '%s %f %f %f %f %f %f', ...    
      'Delimiter',',', 'CollectOutput',1, 'HeaderLines',1);      
fclose(fid);    

M = [datenum(a{1}) a{2}]

fid = fopen('file2.txt', 'rt');  
b = textscan(fid, '%s %f %f %f %f %f %f', ...   
      'Delimiter',',', 'CollectOutput',1, 'HeaderLines',1);   
fclose(fid);   

N = [datenum(b{1}) b{2}]
```

How do i write a 3rd file with all the columns of file 1 and file2 with the matching time stamps  in the same format as file 2 ??

I am trying to write a 3rd file as

```
datetime, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6 ......     A1  A2  A3 A4 .......   
9/15/2010 0:00, 8.8, 3.8, 2.8, 7.3, 0, 9.9    x    
9/15/2010 0:10, 10.1, 8.4, 5.1, 7.7, 0, 8.1    y       
9/15/2010 0:20, 8.8, 5.4, 7.6, 7.1, 0, 10.3    z       
9/15/2010 0:30, 5.7, 8.8, 7.1, 1.6, 0, 6.8     ..  
9/15/2010 0:50, 7.9, 9.2, 6.4, 6.2, 0, 8.4        
9/15/2010 1:20, 0.6, 5.85, 8.1, 9.8, 0, 0.6     ....
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the same as in: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-143J0O/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-143J0O

```
d1=M;
d2=N;
newdat=[d1,zeros(length(d1(:,1)),length(d2(1,2:end)))]; %initialize new matrix with zeros
[m,n]=size(newdat); %get dimensions of new matrix
for i=1:length(d2(:,1)) %loop through data to merge
  indx=find(newdat(:,1)==d2(i,1)); %find existing dates/labels
  if indx
    newdat(indx,[n-length(d2(i,2:end))+1:n])=d2(i,2:end); %if label is matched update the row
  else
    newdat(m+1,[n-length(d2(i,2:end))+1:n])=d2(i,2:end); %if the label is new, create new row
    newdat(m+1,1)=d2(i,1); %insert new label in first column
    m = m+1; %update the dimension of the new matrix
  end
end
newdat=sortrows(newdat); %sort the new matrix
```